# PHP List Content in Directory

Tags: php, html

The code below is able list down nicely all the folders, sub folder and their files.

But I need create this in as a directory.html which will hyperlink to the file. it will be open at a computer so the linking how do I do it, as of now I only can display the content but no hyperlink.

Thanks for helping. !

```
    <?php


$base_dir = 'C:\Users\baoky\Dropbox\SS133A\FINAL PHASE\Documents To Submit';

if (is_dir($base_dir)) 
    scan_directory($base_dir);
else 
    echo 'Invalid base directory. Please check your setting.';

// recursive function to check all dir
function scan_directory($path) {
    if (is_dir($path)) {
        if ($dir_handle = opendir($path)) {
            echo '<ul>';
            while (($file = readdir($dir_handle)) !== false) {
                if ($file != '.' && $file != '..') {
                    if (is_dir($path . '/' . $file)) {
                        echo '<li>';
                        echo '<a href="'.$file.'">'.$file.'</a>';
                        scan_directory($path . '/' . $file);
                        echo '</li>';
                    }
                    else
                        echo "<li><a href=\"$file\">{$file}</a></li>";
                }
            }
            echo '</ul>';
        }
    }
}


?>
```

the issue is with the recursive is not able to get the full path. I did a href but if a folder is inside 1 folder, then in another sub folder , then another sub folder which is folder1/folder2/folder3/file.txt then its display only file.txt which is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`echo "<a href='$file'>$file</a>"` will be the basics of it, though you'd need to build the FULL path leading up the file, since you're doing a recursive dump and only dealing with the "local" sub-path.

Comment: the issue is with the recursive is not able to get the full path. I did a href but if a folder is inside 1 folder,  then in another sub folder , then another sub folder which is folder1/folder2/folder3/file.txt then its display only file.txt which is wrong.

Comment: exactly, `<a href="$path/$file" ...`